# How to add watermarks on Dynamically created textboxes which is placed inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html

I created dynamic textboxes in button click using jQuery. So now I want to add watermarks inside each textbox. How can I do this?

My textbox creation codes

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="5">
    <h1 id="sname3">
        Showtime
        <div id="TextBoxContainer3">
            //Textboxes will be added here//
        </div>
        <br />
    </h1>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```js
$("#btnAdd1").bind("click", function() {
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox3());
    $("#TextBoxContainer3").append(div);

    function GetDynamicTextBox3() {
        return '<input id="dynamictxtbx" name="showtime" type="text" />&nbsp;'
    }
});
```

My watermark text is "Hour:Min:Sec"

Comment: What do you mean by watermark text? Do you have any example of the desired result?

Comment: You mean `placeholder`?

Comment: @JohnR:yes..absolutely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `placeholder` attribute like this.

```
function GetDynamicTextBox3()
{
  return '<input id="dynamictxtbx" name = "showtime" placeholder="Hour:Min:Sec" type="text" />&nbsp;'
}
```